# java parse float without creating a float number with exponential

Tags: java, primitive-types

I'm tring to parse a string to parse like this:

```
Float.parseFloat(value_.toString());
```

when I parse a string number like: "13299802.60" ,
I get this: 1.3299803E7

I want to get the float number like the string without the exponential sign..

How can this be done?

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: you get what you parse, how you visualize it is a totally different story

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead

```
new java.lang.BigDecimal(value_.toString());
```

BigDecimal's are really decimal numbers and not floating point numbers. The scale of 2 (2 decimal digits) will remain

Answer (score 2):

The default output format of float is scientific notation above a certain size.

If you want to output it in normal decimal notation, use NumberFormat with a format string of "#.00" whenever you print it.

Answer (score 1):

float is 32-bit bit and has up to 7 digits or accuracy.  If you want more accuracy, use double which is 64-bit and has up to 16 digits of accuracy (in fact, always use double or BigDecimal)

```
String text = "13299802.60";
System.out.printf("As float %.2f%n", Float.parseFloat(text));
System.out.printf("As double %.2f%n", Double.parseDouble(text));
System.out.println("As BigDecimal "+ new BigDecimal(text));
```

prints

```
As float 13299803.00
As double 13299802.60
As BigDecimal 13299802.60
```